# For Loop in Python:

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, typeerror, callable

This program is for replacing the colors in the list with the color white. why I am getting the `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

```
squares = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "purple", "pink"]

for i in range(0, 7):

    print("before square:", i, "is",squares[i])

    squares[i] = 'white'

    print("after square:", i,"is",squares[i])
```

### output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-bd7b126ebd59> in <module>
      1 squares = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "purple", "pink"]
      2 
----> 3 for i in range(0, 7):

      4     print("before square:",i, "is",squares[i])

      5     `squares[i] = 'white'`

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: The code is running fine. Showing no errors

Comment: me too, version 3.7.7

Comment: Me three, version 3.9.1. Try rebooting/restart??

Comment: Probably at some point in your session you did `range = (0, 7)` or similar. You could confirm with `type(range)` if you're interactive

Answer (score 3):

This code runs fine for me (Python 3.7.6). My best guess for why you are getting this error is that you assigned a tuple to the label (variable) `range` at some other point in the code, so now `range()` won't work for you.

Example:

```
range = (1,2,3,4,5)

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

This throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/shubh/Desktop/a.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in range(10):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: I typed the code in a new notebook and it worked. you guess was right, i did some mistake in the previous part of the program.